# Proving that infinite sum of negligible functions might be not negligible

Tags: functions, infinity

I have to prove that infinite sum of negligible functions might be not negligible. How can I prove that?

I know that a finite sum of negligible functions must be negligible.

thank you

Comment: Summing the same positive-valued function an infinite number of times produces $\infty$ everywhere, which seems nonnegligible.  But that is trivial.  Perhaps you want to add the assumption that the sum converges everywhere?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken then I think you can take $f_{n}$ to be $1$ at $n$ and $0$ elsewhere. The infinite sum is $1$.

Comment: What is your definition of "negligible"?

Comment: @user71352 It is not a negligible function

Comment: @HenningMakholm A negligible function f(x) is a negligible if for every polynomial function p(x),  there exists a n0 such that for all integers n>n0 it holds that f(n)<1/p(n)

Comment: @AdiMl I apologize, I was using the Wikipedia definition which only defined the function on the natural numbers. I think $f_{n}(x)=\chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)$ works and if you sum from $1$ to $\infty$ you just get the function $\chi_{[1,\infty)}(x)$ which is not negligible (this is just a variant of my original comment).

Answer (score 0):

Folowing your def'n in your comment that $f$ is negligible  iff for all $k \in \mathbb N$ we have $f(n)=o(n^{-k})$ as $n\to \infty.$

(1). If $f_m(x)=e^{-x}$ for each $m\in \mathbb N$ then each $f$ is negligible but $\sum_mf_m(x)=\infty.$

(2). Let $[x]$ be the largest integer not exceeding $x.$ Let $f_m(x)=1$ for $x< m+1 $ and $f_m(x)=0$ for $x\geq m+1.$ Then each $f_m$ is negligible but $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}f_m(x)= [x]$ (for $x\geq  1$), which is not negligible.

Answer (score 0):

It's even worse than that: *Every function whatsoever* can be the (pointwise) sum of countably many negligible functions.

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ be arbitrary, and define
$$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & \text{if }n\le |x|<n+1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
Then each $f_n$ is negligible, but
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x) = f(x) $$

These $f_n$ are generally discontinuous, but with a bit more ingenuity you can get each $f_n$ to be continuous, Lipschitz, smooth, etc. provided that $f$ is already similarly nice.

If you want $\sum f_n$ to converge *uniformly*, then you need to require that $f(x)\to 0$ for $x\to\infty$ (but this can be as slow as you like). Then the above construction will still work. On the other hand, it is easy to see that an uniformly converging sum of negligible functions will necessarily satisfy $f(x)\to 0$.